# Unsupported Media Type swagger-ui submitting both json and multipart

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

I am trying to send a json object, an integer, and a file to a spring endpoint. Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
public ResponseEntity<Certificate> create(
        @RequestPart("id")Long id,
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart("certificate") Certificate certificate
) {
   //code
}
```

I am using swagger-ui to send this across, and the UI renders all the fields correctly. See below:
[image]

However, when I try to submit, I get:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-11-02T22:35:20.746+00:00",
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "path": "/certificate/upload"
}
```

Here is the generated curl

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/certificate/upload" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "certificate={ "timestamp": "2021-11-02T22:34:03.187Z", "title": "title" }" -F "id=1" -F "file=@profile_pic.jpeg;type=image/jpeg"
```

Here are the response headers

```
 accept: application/jsonapplication/cborapplication/*+json 
 connection: keep-alive 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Tue02 Nov 2021 22:35:20 GMT 
 keep-alive: timeout=60 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 vary: OriginAccess-Control-Request-MethodAccess-Control-Request-Headers
```

I am not sure how to get the submission from swagger-ui to work correctly.